# The "semisphere" with a horizontal segment is homeomorphic to $S^1$?

Tags: general-topology

Let
$$
X=(\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^{3}: x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}\cap \{z>-1/2\})\cup\{(x,0,0):x\in[-1,1]\}
$$
be the topological space with the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, graphically represented by a "semisphere" with a segment in the ecuator plane joining $(-1,0,0)$ and $(1,0,0)$.

[image]

Intuitively and attending to the graphic, I suppose I can "continuously deform" the space onto

[image]

i.e, onto $Y=(\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^{3}: x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}\cap \{z>0\})\cup\{(x,0,0):x\in[-1,1]\}$. If a have this, it is clear that $X$ is homeomorphic to the open disc with a segment joining two points of the boundary (take the evident projection as the homeomorphism):

[image]

And the open disc with a segment joining two points of the boundary i.e the open disc with two points in the boundary is homeomorphic to $S^{1}$? I suppose some kind of homeomorphism can be constructed, but I don't know how to do it...

I am searching for some hints in two items:

- **Is $X$ homeomorphic to $Y$? If so, how can I construct explicitly an homeomorphism between them?**
- **The disc with two points in the boundary is homeomorphic to $S^1$?**

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
X=(\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^{3}: x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}\cap \{z>-1/2\})\cup\{(x,0,0):x\in[-1,1]\}
$$
There is a continuous deformation in

$$
  Y =(\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^{3}: x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}\cap \{z\gt 0\})\cup\{(x,0,0):x\in[-1,1]\}
$$
So $X$ is homotopically equivalent to Y but they are not homemorphic since X is an open set(is the entire space,considerng it with the topology of subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ as you specified),but Y is not open in X since if you consider ${(,0,0):∈[−1,1]}$ there is no $\epsilon$ such that $B_{(1,0,0)}(\epsilon)\subset Y$since it would contain points with $z<0$,informally the ball take points under the equator for every $\epsilon$.

If I have not misunderstood even the "A=open disc with the segment" is not homeomorphic to $S^1$,since $S^1$ is compact and A not.

I agree with you that there is a deformation from X to $S^1$ and so $\pi_1(X)=\Bbb Z$ but be homotopically equivalent does not help you to say that 2 spaces are homeomorphic. In general you use such invariant to prove that 2 spaces are not homeomorphic.

Comment: Thanks for answering @giorgiokyn23 ! Ok, I see my mistake... By definition of homotopically equivalent, we have $f:X\to Y$ (the continuous deformation from $X$ in $Y$) and $g:Y\to X$ (which can be taken, I suppose, as the inclusion) continuous applications with $g\circ f$ homotopic to $Id_{Y}$ and $f\circ g$ homotopic to $Id_{X}$. Nevertheless, now I have the following problem... How can I construct such $f$? I don't know where to "send" the points in $X\cap \{-1/2 < z\leq 0\}$ in $Y$...

Comment: The same problem arises in the case of the open disc with the segment... which two continuous applications from $S^{1}$ to the open disc with the segment and viceversa should I choose to prove the homotopic equivalence?

Comment: Generally is not easy to show explicitly such  deformation f: X->Y you would show it by some geodetic function which is very hard work. It is very common to show intuitively that such deformation exist. Note well that a deformation is defined if Y is a subset of X and generally does not have an inverse, if it would have a continuous inverse(since the inverse is defined if a map is bijective) then f and g are homeomorphism and it meants that X is Homeomorphic to Y which is in general false. You usually use deformation to find $\pi_1(X)$ not to prove that 2 spaces are homeomorphic